# Add a scroll bar for the preview

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, answers, asking-questions

While typing a post (Q/A) in the editor, below the editing area there is a continuous live update of how the text will look like after publication.

But the problem is, while I am editing some code in the bottom line of the editing area, only the upper portion of the post is visible in the bottom preview pane. If I have to access the preview  of the bottom line, I have to scroll the entire page, and as a result the edit area goes out of vision. This create significant anxiety and losing track of what I was writing.

This can be easily solved. Just like the edit area offers a small scroll bar, add such a small scroll bar in the bottom preview area.